# Life of a photon in gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

I have a simple thought experiment and I am not sure about the answer:

What would happen to a photon that is emitted by an excited hydrogen in an otherwise empty universe?

Would gravity of the atom pull the photon eventually back? How would the frequency of the photon change on the way?

Let's assume this happens in a non-expanding and flat universe. Is there an obvious answer in general relativity to this question?

edit: Assuming a flat universe besides curvature induced by the gravity of atom and photon

Comment: is this off topic? http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In an infinite flat universe nothing will happen. In a closed universe of finite volume, the system will eventually evolve back to the initial state.

Comment: @Hector why do you feel this is off-topic? These seem to me like fairly well-defined questions.

Comment: @Count Iblis: Why do you think nothing would happen in an infinite and flat universe? My understanding is that gravity would change space-time and influence the path of the photon.

Comment: @ScienceAndPhilosophy if the spacetime is flat then there is no gravitational field. Presumably you mean that all curvature is due to the atom.

Comment: @AGML Yes, you are right. I meant flat besides the curvature induced by the photon and hydrogen atom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the spacetime *would be flat* except for the gravitational field of the hydrogen atom. Then to good approximation the spacetime outside the atom is the Schwarzschild spacetime with mass parameter $M = m_H$ i.e. the mass of a hydrogen atom. We will assume the photon is emitted approximately one-half Bohr radius $r_H$ from the centre of the atom.

The Schwarzschild radius of a hydrogen atom $R_s$ is about $2.5\times 10^{-54}$ metres, which is much shorter than $r_H = 2.5 \times 10^{-11}$ metres. Therefore the photon is never pulled back.

Its frequency is redshifted (very slightly) by the atom's gravitational field. Specifically, the frequency at infinity $f_\infty$ is given by

$$ f_\infty = \frac{f_0}{z_\infty+1}$$

where $f_0$ is the frequency measured at emission and the redshift factor to infinity $z_\infty$ is given in this spacetime by

$$z_\infty = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{R_s}{r_h}}} - 1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 10^{-43}}} - 1.$$

This number is zero to within machine epsilon for double precision floats. So for all practical purposes the photon is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess that means that photons never stop and turn around by gravity (at least outside of a black hole). 

Would that mean that a photon generated exactly at the Schwarzschild radius (and trying to escape radially) would just decay and disappear after a while?

I assume this decay would also forbid any elliptical orbits of a photon around a black hole?

Comment: @ScienceAndPhilosophy the Schwartzschild radius is *well inside the nucleus* so this is hard to answer. My understanding is that the photon is a stable particle and would not decay. Various bound photon orbits including elliptic ones do exist; I assumed you meant for the photon to be on an initially radial trajectory.

Comment: hm... you could replace the hydrogen atom with a black hole to make things easier. Never heard about elliptical photon orbits around black holes. I thought there is just a spherical surface of photons around a black hole. Have to do some more reading.